# Connecting to H2 wtih PostgreSQL ODBC Driver

Tags: postgresql, odbc, h2

Successfully started H2 in server mode

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin>java -cp h2-2.0.206.jar org.h2.tools.Server -baseDir ~
TCP server running at tcp://192.168.175.165:9092 (only local connections)
PG server running at pg://192.168.175.165:5435 (only local connections)
Web Console server running at http://192.168.175.165:8082 (only local connections)
```

However, unable to connect using PostgreSQL latest ODBC Driver
13.02

I get this error message:

```
SQL Error. Native Code: 110, SQLState: 42001, Return Code: -1
ERROR: Syntax error in SQL statement "set extra_float_digits[*] = 2"; expected "@, AUTOCOMMIT, EXCLUSIVE, IGNORECASE, PASSWORD, SALT, MODE, DATABASE, COLLATION, CLUSTER, DATABASE_EVENT_LISTENER, ALLOW_LITERALS, DEFAULT_TABLE_TYPE, SCHEMA, CATALOG, SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH, JAVA_OBJECT_SERIALIZER, IGNORE_CATALOGS, SESSION, TRANSACTION, TIME, NON_KEYWORDS, DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING, LOG, STATEMENT_TIMEOUT, CLIENT_ENCODING, CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES, JOIN_COLLAPSE_LIMIT, DATESTYLE, SEARCH_PATH"; SQL statement:
SET extra_float_digits = 2 [42001-206]
DETAIL: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "set extra_float_digits[*] = 2"; expected "@, AUTOCOMMIT, EXCLUSIVE, IGNORECASE, PASSWORD, SALT, MODE, DATABASE, COLLATION, CLUSTER, DATABASE_EVENT_LISTENER, ALLOW_LITERALS, DEFAULT_TABLE_TYPE, SCHEMA, CATALOG, SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH, JAVA_OBJECT_SERIALIZER, IGNORE_CATALOGS, SESSION, TRANSACTION, TIME, NON_KEYWORDS, DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING, LOG, STATEMENT_TIMEOUT, CLIENT_ENCODING, CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES, JOIN_COLLAPSE_LIMIT, DATESTYLE, SEARCH_PATH"; SQL statement:
SET extra_float_digits = 2 [42001-206]
```

Looks like the driver is trying to execute some sql on connecting to the server and when that fails it is failing the connection. Any option to add to the ODBC data source to skip executing the sql that is causing the connection to fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting H2 to the PostgreSQL Compatibility Mode

`jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH`

http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility

Be careful not to change value of `DATABASE_TO_LOWER` after the creation of database.

Comment: No luck. Connection still fails.